# Can my mother apply for a UK spouse visa while she's on vacation in the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, filipino-citizens, spouses

My mother currently holds a tourist visa to the UK. She's now in Manchester with my  step father. She wanted to know if it was possible for her to apply for the spouse visa while she is there or does she have to wait to get back to the Philippines (in July) before she can?

Comment: She needs to go back to Philippines in order to process her application with all supportive evidences

Comment: ^ This is true. But her visiting your step father is good evidence towards the relationship. Make sure she gets some pictures with him there, you can send photo's together with your application.

Answer (score 2):

She’ll need to leave the UK to apply for a family visa if she has permission to be in the UK as a visitor.  Applying to switch to a family visa as a visitor in the UK is only possible if you have either a 6-month family visa as a fiancé, fiancée or proposed civil partner, or permission to stay in the UK for the outcome of a family court case or divorce
https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa

If she lives in the Philippines she has to go back there to apply for this category of visa (see paragraph 28 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-part-1-leave-to-enter-or-stay-in-the-uk) and to gather the required information https://www.gov.uk/uk-family-visa/provide-information

Comment: About the "only" list in the first paragraph: is it truly exhaustive?  What about people on work visas, for example?

Comment: @phoog it refers back to the previous sentence which relates to her being in the U.K. as a visitor. I’ll update if if you think it’s unclear

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks for clarifying.